# Vaadin 14 - BeanManager Class not found

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception, tomcat8.5, vaadin14

I'm testing out Vaadin 14 for a concept product at work. I've already made sure to install `NodeJS (V13.3.0)` and `NPM (6.13.1)`, and included it into my `POM.xml` file.  I am currently using `JRE and JDK V1.8.0.231`

After setting everything up I've run the project on a server which runs on `Tomcat 8.5.49`, and found a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [com.vaadin.cdi.CdiServletDeployer]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:609)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1506)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After cleaning the project folder, server and updating the Maven project I have not seen any improvements.

This is the `Pom.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-project</artifactId>
    <name>Example Project</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <vaadin.version>14.1.2</vaadin.version>

        <drivers.dir>${project.basedir}/drivers</drivers.dir>
        <drivers.downloader.phase>pre-integration-test</drivers.downloader.phase>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>package tomee:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Use the latest released version:
                https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                <version>1.8.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v13.3.0</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.13.1</npmVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tomeeClassifier>webprofile</tomeeClassifier>
                    <context>ROOT</context>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <checkStarted>true</checkStarted>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <simpleLog>true</simpleLog>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <!-- Pass location of downloaded webdrivers to the tests -->
                                <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.17</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>true
                            </onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>
                            <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver
                            </rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                            <downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver_zips
                            </downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                            <customRepositoryMap>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers.xml
                            </customRepositoryMap>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- use phase "none" to skip download step -->
                                <phase>${drivers.downloader.phase}</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>selenium</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I would like to resolve the `ClassNotFoundException` as it does not allow me to view any page that I request. If you need more information to help me, please ask and I will provide as much info as possible.

Comment: The exception is thrown from the class `CdiVaadinServlet.java` and the `BeanManager` is used on line 46.
`Error instantiating servlet class [com.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet]`

Comment: There is another thread posted on https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17990733/unable-to-start-up-vaadin-14-application-breanmanager-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a Jakarta EE container; Tomcat doesn't support Jakarta EE features like CDI.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a way where I can still use Tomcat, as our current technologies are running on it. Do you maybe know of any work around, or similar technologies which I can use?

Comment: You could maybe look into using Spring dependency injection instead of CDI? It has more or less the same features and you can use Spring with Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking at Spring instead, and it works easier.